# PDF Compression from blob storage

Tags: azure-logic-apps, azure-logic-app-standard

Hello i am new to Azure logic app. Currently i am running into problem with PDF compression.

My problem is there are few files already stored in data lake and i want to check their size and if size exceeds 20mb then i need to compress and replace original file with compressed file in the data lake.

Firstly i am fetching data from data-lake and getting the content.And then i am getting metadata of the file and from the metadata i am extracting Size. Then if the size is greater then 20 then i am compressing.

[image: Currently i am getting this error]

[image: This is the following flow]

I am using List of file size for "True". My file sizes are usually more than 150MB. I feel this is the prime factor for the failure of compressor.

Comment: Can you please add your code view masking your credentials

Answer (score 0):

You can use 3rd party connector to do this called `Compress PDF document` of `plumsail` connector. All you need to do is just login into plumsail and get the api for creating the connection. While in the logic app flow, As per your requirement we have used `When a blob is added or modified (properties only) (V2)` and checking if its size is greater than 20 mb using `Condition` connector. If yes, then we are using plumsails `Compress PDF document` and then as per the requirement you can save the file in the same folder with different name or you can save it in another folder of same. For instance i'm saving in container called `documents >20mb`. Here are few screenshots of my logic app for your reference:-

[image]

**Result:**

[image]

**In Storage Account before Compression**

[image]

**In Storage Account after Compression**

[image]

**Scenario when the compressed file is still more than 20mb**
If the file is so large that even after compression it is still greater than 20MB then you can save it in the same folder but with a different name and then delete it after the requirement is completed.

Comment: Thank you for the solution. What type of dynamic content does BLOB has in "Get blob Content "

Comment: @shepard_german just the `List of Files Path`.

Comment: @shepard_german, What type of file are you uploading in your storage account